# Windows Phone - Change Grid Background Color On Button Click

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to change the background color of the grid named `LayoutRoot` to black when you click the button `bgButton` in the application bar. I can't find anything on how to do this through Google or anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the event handler for the button's `Click` event add the following:

```
LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Cyan );
```

It doesn't have to be a [`SolidColorBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), it can be any class derived from [`Brush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), such as [`LinearGradientBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), [`RadialGradientBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.radialgradientbrush%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) etc.

---

You can also use a binding instead of explicitly setting the color for the `Grid`.

In XAML

```
<Grid Background="{Binding RootBackground}">
...
</Grid>
```

In your ViewModel

```
public Brush RootBackground
{
  get { return _rootBackground; }
  set 
  {
    if( value != _rootBackground ) {
      _rootBackground = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged( "RootBackground" );
    }
   }
}
private Brush _rootBackground = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Transparent );
```

In the button event handler

```
RootBackground = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Cyan );
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks :) Don't know if you can help with my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563191/windows-phone-7-access-camera-flash

Comment: @Rev Sorry, I've never messed with the camera. Also, you selected my answer before I got a chance to add some more details, so take another look :-)

Comment: Ah, that's okay, I'm sure someone will be able to figure it out. And nice, thanks for all that info :)