# How to set background for Grid in .cs in windowsphone?

Tags: grid, windows-phone, background-color

I want to set one color for Grid in .cs. Can you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone - Change Grid Background Color On Button Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563657/windows-phone-change-grid-background-color-on-button-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
myGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 100, 100, 100));
```

**EDIT:**

It doesn't have to be a SolidColorBrush, it can be any class derived from Brush, such as LinearGradientBrush, RadialGradientBrush etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can set like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ContentPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
}
```

or

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ContentPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(value of A, value of R, value of G, value of B));
}
```